# macOS Cataline 10.15.7 crashing due to kernel panic in USB

Tags: macos, usb, kernel-panic

I keep getting this crash while the computer sleeps: https://pastebin.com/dFGvusQD.

It seems that it has to do with a USB device? Is it because I unplugged my hard drive a while ago?

Any known workarounds?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Only started happening about a week ago and never got these crashes prior. Can you report the version of your firmware and BridgeOS version?

Comment: Where can I find those? @Forge